# What is difference between objects.all().annotate and objects.annotate?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

Currently I am practicing for annotate and have some confusion regarding below code.

```
>>> b = Book.objects.all().annotate(upper_name = Upper('name'))
>>> b[0].name
'Book1'
>>> b[0].upper_name
'BOOK1'
>>> ba = Book.objects.annotate(upper_name = Upper('name'))
>>> ba[0]
<Book: Book1>
>>> ba[0].name
'Book1'
>>> ba[0].upper_name
'BOOK1'
```

I am getting same output when not using `all()` so what is difference between using `Book.objects.all()` and 'Book.objects.annotate()'.

How doing `annotate()` on Book objects without `all()` provide all Book objects.

I have read Django documentation but not able to find any answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference because `all` actually calls `get_queryset` on model manager to return queryset. You can check the [implementation](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1fe3e2426469d22977a2a17750959b17877b557d/django/db/models/manager.py#L139) of `BaseManager` to see this.

Using `all()` is preferable because it's guaranteed to return a [QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/) instance that you can further iterate/filter/etc, where using manager returns [Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/) instance that you can filter/annotate/whatever but can't use in same way as queryset.

Example:

```
for book in Book.objects:
    # this will fail

for book in Book.objects.all():
    # this will work
```

Comment: So which one is most preferable way & why ?

Comment: I extended answer - please check.